# Choosing a column within a python class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I have a pandas dataframe with index, open, high, low, close, ...

I have created a class and want to be able to create a function within the class, at the moment called field_type that returns me a desired field from my dataframe. If I change the final line to return self.items.close it works fine, but I want it to be dynamic.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
class sma():
    def __init__(self, items, navg, field ='close'):
       self.items = items
       self.navg = navg
       self.field = field 

   def field_type(self):
       return self.items.field
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return getattr(self.items, self.field)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_